# How can I match list elements with tuple elements?

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following lists and tuple lists:

```py
adsh_list_sub
['0000007084-22-000008', '0000766421-22-000009', '0000320193-22-000007']
```

```py
cik_list
['7084', '766421', '320193']
```

```py
adsh_cik_tuple
[('0000007084-22-000008', '7084'),
 ('0000766421-22-000009', '766421'),
 ('0000320193-22-000007', '320193')]
```

```py
adsh_list_num
['0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000320193-22-000007',
 '0000320193-22-000007',
 '0000766421-22-000009',
 '0000766421-22-000009',
 '0000320193-22-000007',
 '0000320193-22-000007',
 '0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000007084-22-000008',
 '0000320193-22-000007',
 '0000320193-22-000007',
 '0000007084-22-000008']
```

Note that 
 (1) all elements in 'adsh_list_num' are elements of 'adsh_list_sub' 
(2) all elements in 'adsh_list_num' are paired to a cik element through 'adsh_cik_tuple'

*How can I generate a new list 'cik_num' such that 'cik_num' is identical to 'adsh_list_num' except that it contains not the adsh element but the cik element from 'adsh_cik_tuple'?*

(In this example, the string of the cik element need not always be contained in the 'adsh' element.)

Expected output:

```py
['7084',
 '7084',
 '320193',
 '320193',
 '766421',
 '766421',
 '320193',
 '320193',
 '7084',
 '7084',
 '7084',
 '7084',
 '7084',
 '7084',
 '320193',
 '320193',
 '7084']
```

Comment: Could you write out what your expected output is for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from the list of tuples, and then use a list comprehension to read off the result using the generated mapping:

```py
mapping = dict(adsh_cik_tuple)
[mapping[item] for item in adsh_list_num]
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 '7084', '7084', '320193', '320193', '766421', '766421', '320193', '320193', 
 '7084', '7084', '7084', '7084', '7084', '7084', '320193', '320193', '7084'
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, but how can I work with this output as a list? It's a dictionary, but I need a list. When I do print(mapping) I get {'0000007084-22-000008': '7084', '0000766421-22-000009': '766421', '0000320193-22-000007': '320193'}

Comment: The output is already a list.

Comment: Can you help me store it in a variable? I want to add this new list as a new column to a pandas dataframe and I don't know how to do it if it isn't in a single variable

Comment: `variable_name = [mapping[item] for item in adsh_list_num]`